# Escape symbol '<%=' and '%>'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, escaping, chart.js

How can I escape these characters so that I can print it in the view

- `<%=`
- `%>`

I am using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) on the view and on it's javascript code it needs those characters:

```
var appPerMonthTrendChart = new Chart(ctxAppPerMonth).Line(dataAppPerMonth, { 
    responsive: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth : 3,
    multiTooltipTemplate: <%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %>%"
});
```

The parameter `multiTooltipTemplate` defines the template of the tool-tip of the chart and the paramter was defined like the closing and openning tag of the rails code in view. Is there a way to print those characters so that the client can see it like that?

Comment: What is your current js filename?

Comment: Change the file extension to `filename.js.erb` so that codes inside erb tag gets compiled. Inserting values like this is expected when you are instantiating the js object, otherwise doing it using ajax is always preferred.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed It's not a js file though. It has an `.html.erb` extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second `%` to the opening tag like this:

```
responsive: true,
datasetStrokeWidth : 3,
multiTooltipTemplate: <%%= datasetLabel %>: <%%= value %>"
```

Comment: If you are using it in asp.net page you can escape it by using this syntax "<\%=datasetLabel%> : <\%=value%>"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it in aspx page you can escape it by using this syntax. adding backslash in front of %

`"<\%=datasetLabel%> : <\%=value%>"`